# What is the difference between a method returning a task and an async method returning a task?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to see what difference does adding async to a method which returns a task make.

**Method in controller:**

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSomeData()
    {
        var result = await _myService.GetAString();            

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

**In MyService**:

```
public Task<String> GetAString()
{
    return _repository.GetAStringAsync();
}
```

**In repository:**

```
public async Task<String>GetAStringAsync()
    {
        return await ......configureawait(false)
    }
```

Adding async await to the Service method works just fine. But what is the difference between these two service methods then?    The only difference I can spot is that using version 2 I can use configureAwait(false)

```
**In MyService: ( cannot use configureawait)**


public Task<String> GetAString()
        {
            return _repository.GetAStringAsync();
        }
```

And
        **In MyService: (can use configure await)**

```
public async Task<String> GetAString()
        {
            return await _repository.GetAStringAsync();
        }
```

Thanks